# Adding the event id to the HTML Full Calendar generates

Tags: fullcalendar

I using Full Calendar within a MS Access Form web browser control.  Both Full Calendar and Access load events from the same MySQL database. This provides a drag and drop facility within Access.

I can pass the event title to Access  using the InnerText property but event titles are not unique and therefore cannot be used to retrieve the event record in Access.

Using InnerHTML and OuterHTML I can capture the entire DIV

Whilst I could make the event title unique by adding the event id I'd prefer to modify the InnerHTML written by Full Calendar to include the event id as an HTML Id which I could then extract.
Is this possible and if so can someone  suggest how ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by using the **className** property of the Full Calendar Event object.  I assign a class name equal to the id and this then appears in the HTML.

**wbbControl.Document.activeElement.parentElement.outerhtml** grabs the HTML for the parent of the selected item DIV. (wbbControl is the Access Web Browser Control).